# Display current date

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date

Below are some parts of my java code that query an sqlite database. How do i add an auto current date when i save my data? the _DATE and _TIME i used is using textfields, but i wanted to use display current date when i save the diary

```
private static final String DIARY_TABLE = "diarytable";
        private static final String _ID = "id";
        private static final String _NAME = "workout";
        private static final String _DATE = "date";
        private static final String _TIME = "time";
        private static final String _NOTES = "notes";

        public data(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
            this.context=context;
        }



        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            try{
               // db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + UID + " integer primary key autoincrement," +
                        "" + NAME + " VARCHAR(50), " +
                        "" + _STATUS + " VARCHAR(255)," +
                        "" + WEIGHT + " VARCHAR(255));");
                message.mess(context,"Database Created");

 //               db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE1);
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ DIARY_TABLE+ " ( "+_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement," +
                        ""+_NAME+" VARCHAR(50), " +
                        ""+_DATE+" VARCHAR(10)," +
                        ""+_TIME+" VARCHAR(5)," +
                        ""+_NOTES+" VARCHAR(255));");
                message.mess(context,"Second Database Created");

            }
            catch(SQLException e){
                message.mess(context, "Failed" +e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe this would help http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-get-current-date-time-date-and-calender/

Comment: @e4c5 Not really such a thing as a proper date-time data type in SQLite. The [SQLite data types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) are loosey-goosey, more of a suggestion than a data-type. In particular, the doc says: "SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times". One reason why I suggest the [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)) over SQLite when one is doing more serious database work.

Comment: @BasilBourque  you got me there! I wasn't thinking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple way to display current date time. Below code I used in my project.

```
    TextView date1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvdatetime);
    time1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvtime);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    dt1 = sdf.format(new Date());
    // textView is the TextView view that should display it
    date1.setText(dt1);
    datevalue=date1.getText().toString();
    //Shows Current time 
    Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
    today.setToNow();
    time1.setText(today.format("%k:%M:%S"));
    timevalue=time1.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
 String getCurrentDateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
 String getCurrentDate = new SimpleDateFormatDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Know the date format you would like to store into db. 
   `Eg. dd/MM/yyyy, MM-dd-yyyy`
2. Get the date from system
3. Format the system date to the format you declared.

Here's the code

```
   DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

The result would be something like this `2015/09/15`. You can then store the date into your database.

Comment: i used the code that you gave but it didn't show all the date